# One y axis data point there but it's x axis data point missing in weekly chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

- Here below code plase any look if they know thank you.
- In it 1 weeks (5 day) data points excluding saturday and sunday but x
  axis 1 days (21 may) data point missing.
- 2 seris of data both series contain date and price in itlike share price value for that day
- In attachment all x data point showing but all not distributed equally i don,t want like this img

```js
                var series_a = [{"close":1814,"date":"2021\/05\/19"},{"close":1772,"date":"2021\/05\/20"},{"close":1752,"date":"2021\/05\/21"},{"close":1793,"date":"2021\/05\/24"},{"close":1817,"date":"2021\/05\/25"},{"close":1850,"date":"2021\/05\/26"}];
                var series_b = [{"close":1764,"date":"2021\/05\/19"},{"close":1752,"date":"2021\/05\/20"},{"close":1787,"date":"2021\/05\/21"},{"close":1791,"date":"2021\/05\/24"},{"close":1790,"date":"2021\/05\/25"},{"close":1804,"date":"2021\/05\/26"}];
    
                tickDataPoint = series_b.map(function(e) {
                    return new Date(e.date).getTime()
                });
                series_a = series_a.map(function(e) {
                    return [new Date(e.date).getTime(), e.close, ]
                });
                series_b = series_b.map(function(e) {
                    return [new Date(e.date).getTime(), e.close, ]
                });
    
                const timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    global: {
                        timezoneOffset: timezone
                    }
                });
    
                var a = Highcharts.stockChart('dips_stock_div_aptech', {
                    chart: {
                        width: 790,
                        height: 280,
                    },
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        opposite: false,
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },   
                    plotOptions: {
                        // line: {
                        //  dataLabels: {
                        //          enabled: true
                        //  },
                        //  enableMouseTracking: false
                        //      //  }
                        //      series: {
                        //     gapSize: 12
                        // }    
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        // ordinal:true,
                        type: 'datetime', 
                        // gridLineWidth: 1,
                        // tickInterval: null,
                        // step: 1,
                    // alignTicks:true,
                    tickInterval: 1 , // 2 month
                    // tickWidth:0,
                    // categories: tickDataPoint,  tickInterval: 1,
                    breaks: [{
                        from: 1621535400000,
                        to: 1621708200000,
                        // breakSize: 1
                    }],
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            // return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%e-%Y', this.value)
                            const index = tickDataPoint.findIndex(tickDataPoint => tickDataPoint == this.value);
                            console.log(tickDataPoint+'-------'+this.value); // 3
                            console.log(index); // 3
                            if (index>=0){
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e\'%b', this.value);
                            }else{
                                return '';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                            name: "Astral Ltd",
                            data: series_a,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "BSE Sensex",
                            data: series_b,
                        }
                    ],
                    navigator: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                });
```

```html
    <HTML>
    <BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <div id="dips_stock_div_aptech" style="overflow: visible;width:100%;margin:10px;margin-top: -5px;"></div>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>

[![in img all data points showing but x data point not distributed equally date 22 and 23 may taking long space][1]][1]
```

Comment: Hi @santosh vishwakarma, I am not sure what result you want to achieve. Could you specify the questions? The missing x-axis label is caused by using breaks.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek you can remove breaks but some issues come there. Just I want 5 data points x-axis it should equally be distributed.

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/brxy1pkj/ Do you mean something like that?